# getting nullpointerexception while adding resources in arquillian

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am trying to add a file from the project directory in arquillian but getting nullPointerException

```
   validXml="META-INF/validXml.xml";

    @InjectMocks
Validator validator;


   @Deployment
public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
    return ShrinkWrap
            .create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addClasses(Validator.class)
            .addAsLibraries(libs)
            .addAsResource("validXml.xml", "META-INF/validXml.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<beans/>"), "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<web-app></web-app>"),
                    "web.xml");
}

@Test
public void validatorTestor(){
        String validLine;
        BufferedReader bufferedReaderValid = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(new File(validXmlFile)));

        validPayload = new StringBuilder();

        while ((validLine = bufferedReaderValid.readLine()) != null) {
            validPayload.append(validLine.trim());
        }

        Assert.assertEquals(true,validator.validator(validPayload));

    }
```

this is the exception i am getting ::

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.sample.common.exception.SampleException> but was<java.lang.NullPointerException>
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:226)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at    org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:65)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:160)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:126)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:90)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

getting error in `validPayload` as `validXml` is not picking up,giving nullPointerException,tried putting the file in `src/test/resources` but no result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Whenever you get an exception, always print the full stack trace here. Also, let us knwo which line exactly is flagged.

Comment: You need to show us the Validator class or atleast the method which is under test.